# Data sharing/replication among some specific nodes in a distributed database or memory grid

Tags: database, distributed-system

I have a requirement where i need to share the data in between the specific nodes of a distributed cluster.

For example, nodes A, B , C, D have been setup in a cluster. Now, the data which is shared between nodes A and B, should not be accessible and visible to node C and D in the cluster. 
Another dataset, let us say, can be shared among A, B, C then D should not be able to view it.

Cluster can be either a memory grid or a distributed database. Is it possible and how (except of queues, blockchain and esbs)?